# malloc not allocating properly with pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc, free

I am trying to create a function that allocates memory of a certain specified size. In the main, I create the pointer and then send the pointer and the size to the function for memory to be allocated. For some reason it causes all sorts of problems. My program works smoothly if I use the malloc in the main, but not through the function.

```
int main(void){
    int * pointer;
    int array_size = SIZE;
    ...
    allocate_memory(&pointer,array_size);
    ...
    free(pointer);
}

allocate_memory(int *pointer,int size){
    *pointer = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(!(*pointer)){
        printf("Memory allocation fail!");
        exit(0);
    }
```

The problem now is that it gives me an error when I try to free the memory.
I would appreciate it if the solution will come with a short explanation. I am starting to be very confused about how these pointers and castings are working. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pick up any standard book.The whole `pointer to pointer` and `pointer to variable` thing is explained well with graphics,figures and elementary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were many errors in your program which I am pointing out:

1. You need to `#define` the macro `SIZE` as otherwise the program just won't know what it is.
2. It's better to declare a prototype of the function `allocate_memory()` so that any discrepancy in type of arguments or return type is detected
3. You had passed `&pointer` as an argument to `allocate_array()` in `main()`.For this it is necessary to define the function as `allocate_memory(int **pointer,int size)` instead of `allocate_memory(int *pointer,int size)` which you have done.
4. `if(*pointer==NULL)` implements the condition in a much simpler way and serves just the same purpose.
5. Use `exit(1)` for unsuccessful termination as `exit(0)` is used to denote successful termination.
6. Never ignore warnings.It's not a good practice.

Here's the corrected code.It compiles well without warnings and does the job (memory allocation) as intended.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #define SIZE 30

    void allocate_memory(int**,int);

    int main(void){
        int * pointer;
        int array_size = SIZE;
        allocate_memory(&pointer,array_size);
        free(pointer);
    }

    void allocate_memory(int **pointer,int size)
    {
        *pointer = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        if(*pointer==NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation fail!");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            printf("\nMemory allocation successful");


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am very new to this forum and therefore I foolishly thought I did not have to add my prototypes to the code I supplied. In MY code, those prototypes did exist. I merely assumed people would interpret them as if they were a given.

Comment: @AYR Welcome to StackOverflow.People here appreciate good and sincere questions even if it's from beginners.

Comment: @SheerFish -1 ,Creating a memory leak is not good, you are also causing undefined behavour with `free( pointer )`. Remeber in C is variables are passed by value. You are lacking basic knowledge of C. Im only trying to help you if you disagree we can star a chat and i will gladly explain.

Comment: @Armin Read more about `free()` and you'll know what it `really` does.

Comment: @SheerFish Print your values of pointer in your code before and after `allocate_memory`  and you will see pointer was not changed.

Comment: @Armin What has it got to do with `pass-by-value`?`free()` simply deallocates the address pointed,it doesn't change the value of the pointer.

Comment: @SheerFish Again your code with printf clearly showing pointer in the main was not changed. 
http://ideone.com/gvzURO

Comment: @SheerFish Now that you finally came to the right code, are you willing to admit my code was correct?

Comment: @Armin Why are you unwilling to admit your `allocate_memory(int **pointer,size)` is wrong?

Comment: @SheerFish :D Oh you are talking about me forgetting to type int before size, that was a typo.

Comment: @Armin OK, you concede your `int size` typo and I concede my `**pointer` typo.Peace!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29023/discussion-between-sheer-fish-and-armin)